# How to select/reduce a list of dictionaries in Flask/Jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a Jinja template with a list of dictionaries. Order matters. I'd like to reduce the list or lookup values based on the keys/values of the dictionaries. Here's an example:

```
{%
    set ordered_dicts = [
        {
            'id': 'foo',
            'name': 'My name is Foo'
        },
        {
            'id': 'bar',
            'name': 'My name is Bar'
        }
    ]
%}
```

If I have a variable `some_id = 'foo'`, how do I get `'My name is Foo'` out of `ordered_dicts` in my Jinja template?

I tried [`select()`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#select) and [`selectattr()`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#selectattr) but couldn't figure them out based on the documentation. Here's what I tried:

```
{{ ordered_dicts|selectattr("id", "foo") }}
```

That outputs:

```
<generator object _select_or_reject at 0x10748d870>
```

I don't think I'm understanding the use of `select()` and `selectattr()` properly.

Do I need to iterate over the list and do the lookup manually?

---

**Update:**

As codegeek and gipi pointed out, I need to do something like this with the generator:

```
{{ ordered_dicts|selectattr("id", "foo")|list }}
```

The resulting error: `TemplateRuntimeError: no test named 'foo'`, which clarifies how `selectattr()` works. The second argument has to be one of [the builtin tests](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#list-of-builtin-tests). As far as I can tell, none of these tests will let me check whether the value associated with a key matches another value. Here's what I'd like to do:

```
{{ ordered_dicts|selectattr("id", "sameas", "foo")|list }}
```

But that doesn't work, since the `sameas` test checks whether two objects are really the same object in memory, not whether two strings/numbers are equivalent.

So is it possible to pick an item based on a key/value comparison test?

Comment: You need to iterate over it further since you are getting a generator object.

Comment: should be equalto, but I can't seem to get this one to work myself

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've just backported `equalto` like this:

```
app.jinja_env.tests['equalto'] = lambda value, other : value == other
```

After that [this example from 2.8 docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#equalto) works:

```
{{ users|selectattr("email", "equalto", "foo@bar.invalid") }}
```

*Update*: Flask has a decorator for registering tests, slightly cleaner syntax: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.template_test

Comment: Googled it again and found my own answer. :)

Comment: Same pb for me. Where do you put the piece of code app.jinja_env. ... ? What is app in your example ? Can you past a real complete piece of code please ? Thx in advance.

Comment: `equalto` is a default jinja test https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#eq

Answer (score 7):

For people who don't have selectattr (e.g. you're stuck with Jinja2.6), and don't want to make yet another custom filter, these 2 lines will solve your problem real quick.

```
{% set selection = [] %}
{% for x in biglist if x.criteria == 'pickme' %}{% do selection.append(x) %}{% endfor %}
```

Comment: "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: Encountered unknown tag 'do'

Comment: @jmcollin92 instead of  `{% do selection.append(x) %}` use `{{ selection.append(x) }}`. It should work.

Answer (score 3):

`select()` and `selectattr()` act upon a `list` and return a `list`, so if you know that there is only one result take the first from the generator, i.e

`{{ oredered_dicts|selectattr("id", "foo")|first }}`

**Note:** code not tested

Comment: That helps, but still not quite there. Updating my question.

Comment: selectattr returns a generator, you may want to convert it to a list `{{ oredered_dicts|selectattr("id", "foo")|list|count }}`

Answer (score 2):

Have a look to https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/8836 for this issue.

A solution/workaround is to create a file filter_plugins/core.py in your workbook directory with the following content:

```
def filter_list(list, key, value):
    return filter(lambda t: t[key] == value, list)

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'byattr': filter_list
        }
```

And use it so:

```
{{ ordered_dicts|byattr("id", "foo") }}
```

Answer (score 1):

More natural way for Ansible is to create /etc/ansible/test_plugins/custom.py with content

```
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)
__metaclass__ = type

from ansible import errors

def equalto(value, other):
    return bool(value == other)

class TestModule(object):
    ''' Ansible file jinja2 tests '''

    def tests(self):
        return {
            'equalto' : equalto,
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the *equalto* filter is coming in Jinja2.8 ([changelog](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/changelog/)) but it doesn't have any release date set yet (24 Feb 2014). As a workaround I'd suggest using *groupby* filter:

```
<ul>
{% for group in persons|groupby('gender') %}
    <li>{{ group.grouper }}<ul>
    {% for person in group.list %}
        <li>{{ person.first_name }} {{ person.last_name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}</ul></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```