# Returning list of dictionaries with jinja2

Tags: python, dictionary, jinja2

I have a list of dictionaries like so:

```
[{
    submarket: <*submarket_name*>,
    projects: [{
        *...list of dictionaries containing project details*
    }]
}]
```

Bascially, each entry in my dictionary is a submarket name followed by a list of that submarket's projects; each project is its own dictionary.

When a user selects a submarket, I want to print out that submarket's projects.  I'm having difficulty getting the actual project list.  I looked at the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529234/how-to-select-reduce-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-flask-jinja/38242777) and am able to do:

```
{% for item in data | selectattr('submarket', 'equalto', 'ABC') %}
```

to get the dictionary entry for submarket "ABC".  But I want just the `projects` list, so I can loop through that in my template.  After reading the documentation, I would have thought,

```
{% for item in data | selectattr('submarket', 'equalto', 'ABC') | attr('projects') %}
```

Would give me the projects list, but it apparently returns nothing.  What am I missing?

EDIT:  I had considered nesting another for loop inside the above filter, i.e.,

```
{% for item in data | selectattr('submarket', 'equalto', 'ABC') %}
    {% for proj in item.project %}
    ...etc
```

but this shouldn't be necessary.  Can't I just get straight to the project list?

Comment: Rather than dealing with this in template, I'd suggest you to prepare the data in your view in a format which will be straightforward to display in template.

Comment: You're right & I'll rethnk my approach.  Still, it would be nice to know how to get the value of the  `projects` field.